# Finding an issue while removing common id from 2Tables-Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SET @sql =   CONCAT('SELECT ', (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME) FROM 
information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = 'i2049127_wp1' AND table_name = 
'wp3_wpsp_ticket' AND column_name NOT IN ('wt.guest_name', 'wt.guest_email')), 
' from i2049127_wp1.wp3_wpsp_ticket wt,i2049127_wp1.wp3_wpsp_catagories wc   where wt.cat_id=wc.id limit 1');

PREPARE data FROM @sql;

EXECUTE data;
```

Trying to join 2 tables But i am getting an error as shown below

[image]

Comment: Print out the query string after you have created it and the answer should be obvious.

Comment: Sounds like both of your tables have an `id` column in them. To @GordonLinoff's point, you would see that if you looked at what is loaded into your `@sql` variable after it's been set in that first line.  I'm not familiar with your client, but it looks like the `2` and `3` may be links to the queries that were attempted and failed in the error's `Error in query 2 3` line.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i am getting ambiguous column name because both  the table contains column name as "id"...

Comment: @JNevill you point is correct is there any chance of creating alias for id

Comment: perhaps `GROUP_CONCAT(table_name || '.' || COLUMN_NAME)` so that your resulting SQL string is explicitly naming the table to which the column belongs. Also `GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(table_name,'.', COLUMN_NAME,' AS ',table_name,'_',COLUMN_NAME))` to get super fancy with the alias so you don't leave MySQL to name your duplicate columns in the result set for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need it, the easiest thing to do is remove `id` from the columns being selected:

```
SET @sql =   CONCAT('SELECT ',
                    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME) FROM 
information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = 'i2049127_wp1' AND table_name = 
'wp3_wpsp_ticket' AND column_name NOT IN ('wt.guest_name', 'wt.guest_email', 'id')), 
                  ' from i2049127_wp1.wp3_wpsp_ticket wt  join i2049127_wp1.wp3_wpsp_catagories wc on wt.cat_id = wc.id limit 1');
```

If you do need it, you need to decide which one:

```
SET @sql =   CONCAT('SELECT ',
                    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT((CASE WHEN COLUM_NAME = 'id' THEN 'wt.id' ELSE COLUMN_NAME END)) FROM 
information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = 'i2049127_wp1' AND table_name = 
'wp3_wpsp_ticket' AND column_name NOT IN ('wt.guest_name', 'wt.guest_email')), 
                  ' from i2049127_wp1.wp3_wpsp_ticket wt join i2049127_wp1.wp3_wpsp_catagories wc on wt.cat_id = wc.id limit 1');
```

Note that I also fixed the archaic `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: I am getting error for the second option. Actually i need to preserve wt.id

Comment: Error: Error in query (1064): Syntax error near 'FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = 'i2049127_wp1' AND table_' at line 2

Comment: ((CASE WHEN COLUM_NAME = 'id' THEN 'wt.id' ELSE COLUMN_NAME END)

syntax error---close bracket and column 

(CASE WHEN COLUMN_NAME = 'id' THEN 'wt.id' ELSE COLUMN_NAME END))

Answer (score 0):

I agree with above comments except small mistakes

```
SET @sql =   CONCAT('SELECT ',
                (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT((CASE WHEN COLUMN_NAME = 'id' THEN 'wt.id' ELSE COLUMN_NAME END)) FROM 
information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = 'i2049127_wp1' AND table_name = 
'wp3_wpsp_ticket' AND column_name NOT IN ('wt.guest_name', 'wt.guest_email')), 
' from i2049127_wp1.wp3_wpsp_ticket wt join i2049127_wp1.wp3_wpsp_catagories wc on wt.cat_id = wc.id limit 1');
```